# Simplify fractional result of custom number format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets I would like to express any decimal number to the nearest 32nd of an inch. If I type `1.537` I want the result to be `1 17/32`, but if I type `1.5` I need it to be expressed as `1 1/2` not `1 16/32` nor `48/32`, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

With **`# ??/32`** you are locking it only to **"/32"** fractions. For variable fractions you need to use:

```
#??/??
```

[image: 0]

Comment: right I didn't specify but I also need them to output as mixed numbers not improper fractions. If I have 1.5 I like it to show as 1 1/2 not 3/2.

Comment: @fred in that case use: `# ??/??` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qW8c.png

Comment: This doesn't round to the nearest 32nd as intended, I edited my question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: well, you can't have both its either `# ??/??` or `#??/??` or `# ??/32`or `#??/32`

Answer (score 1):

This worked great for me when I had the same question:
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/fractex1.htm

Conceptually, round to the closest 1/32 (or whatever fraction you want) and then display format to the simplified fraction.

I used this formula:

```
=ROUND(A1*32,0)/32
```

With this display format: `# ??/??`